# How to read debug log in Eclipse

Tags: java, android

I'm running the following code....

```
package com.dc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class DC extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try
        {
            // this is the code that I am surrounding in the try/catch block
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //init webview
            WebView DCWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

            //when a link is clicked, use the WebView instead of opening a new browser
            DCWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {
                public void launchExternalBrowser(String url) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent); 
                }
            });

            //enable javascript
            WebSettings webViewSettings = DCWebView.getSettings();
            webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // this is the line of code that sends a real error message to the log
            Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());

            // this is the line that prints out the location in
            // the code where the error occurred.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This stack trace isn't incredibly helpful.  I'm just learning java/android (I have a background in PHP)

```
11-20 21:22:43.892: ERROR/ERROR(1032): ERROR IN CODE: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 21:22:43.892: WARN/System.err(1032): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 21:22:43.902: WARN/System.err(1032):     at com.dealclippings.DealClippings.onCreate(DealClippings.java:24)
11-20 21:22:43.902: WARN/System.err(1032):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-20 21:22:43.912: WARN/System.err(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
11-20 21:22:43.912: WARN/System.err(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
11-20 21:22:43.922: WARN/System.err(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-20 21:22:43.922: WARN/System.err(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
11-20 21:22:43.932: WARN/System.err(1032):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 21:22:43.932: WARN/System.err(1032):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-20 21:22:43.942: WARN/System.err(1032):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
11-20 21:22:43.942: WARN/System.err(1032):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 21:22:43.952: WARN/System.err(1032):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-20 21:22:43.952: WARN/System.err(1032):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-20 21:22:43.962: WARN/System.err(1032):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-20 21:22:43.962: WARN/System.err(1032):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: NullPointerException means that you're trying to use a value that's set to null. For instance, if DCWebView is null and you try to call `DCWebView.setWebViewClient`, you will get a NullPointerException. The stack trace just tells you where to look for this problem. Line 24 of DealClippings.java seems to be the issue.

Comment: Please avoid non-static-final variable names starting with upper-case letters; conventionally they'll start with lower-case letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a NullPointerException in the file DealClippings line 24

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at   
   com.dealclippings.DealClippings.onCreate(DealClippings.java:24)
```